# TPLink Archer A6 WDS wireless bridging isn't working with Syrotech Router

Tags: wireless-router

TPLink Archer A6 WDS wireless bridging isn't working with new Syrotech Router. It works with other TPLink router but not with new Syrotech router that ISP provided. It isn't connecting to that new router.

Comment: Did you turn bridge mode ON new router?   ....... https://gist.github.com/cmangla/6e6e15deed7435ebb2bddfaf3e77b5de

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.